Jira API key can't access issues or sprints that were created after its last login
I'm building an application that uses the Jira REST API. The application has its own service account with its own jira login separate from any individual account.
As a one-off setup step, I have logged into Jira as the service account, and generated an API token from this page: https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens.
Initially everything worked fine. However over time the application started getting 401 errors on some requests, especially when trying to access recently created issues, epics, and sprints. Once I go and log back into Jira manually as the service account, the application seems to start working again.
My current theory is that API keys can only access entities (issues, epics, sprints, etc) that existed at the time of the last login on the account that owns the API key. So for a service account that no one ever logs into, it gradually loses access to the most recent data.
Is my theory correct? And is there a way around it if so? I don't want to have to log in as the service account every now and then to "refresh" its access.


Is my theory correct?

It sounds highly unlikely.
I've got a number of service accounts running in various Jira instances for interacting with the REST API and they've never behaved like that. Any time I start getting random 401s for previously working requests it's because someone changed the permissions for that account at the Project / Issue / Board level without understanding the implications.
I'd be inclined to look closer at the permissions of the affected objects using a Project Admin / Jira Admin account to ease your concerns that using the service account via the UI is somehow a 'reset' mechanism.

First of all, theory is not correct since Atlassian's API keys are not working like that. If you generate an API key for your user and you are using it in a request, basically you should have same access with your regular user from UI.
There are bunch of things you may check:

Is your implementation logging the ErrorCollection that returns from the request? If you face with an "error" on a HTTP request (i.e 400, 401, 500, etc), the response contains a collection of errors that you should check for this operation, in order to understand what's wrong.
Can you do the same operation with your own user on Jira UI (from the browser)? If the data you want to get is also not opening from the browser, the issue is related with your (the user's) permission on the Jira system.

These two should be enough for your case. If you are getting 401 for the data that you can able to get before, usually someone changed something in the permission schema or roles; and your user is not placed in this new change.
